# PHP - Dynamically append web page to sitemap.xml

Tags: php, simplexml, sitemap

I have a site that searches through a database of websites. I am trying to get to append an url to sitemap.xml whenever the search returns a single result. I know I would need to use simplexml but I'm not sure how to implement it.

**Pseudo Code**

```
if (correct results) {
    $theDate = date('c',time());
    $theUrl = "http://myurl.com/?r=asdfasdf1234"
    appendtositemap($theDate, $theUrl);
}
```

**Current sitemap.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>http://example.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2013-04-08T20:38:15+00:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
        <priority>1.0</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first want to parse what you already have, if you're adding on to it:

```
$sitemap = simplexml_load_string(YOUR_ORIGINAL_XML_HERE_AS_A_STRING);
```

After that, let's say you want to create a new url node. You can do this by using the `addChild` function on any `SimpleXMLElement` (this creates a child XML node, or the nested node structure you see above):

```
$myNewUri = $sitemap->addChild("url");
$myNewUri->addChild("loc", "http://www.google.com/");
$myNewUri->addChild("lastmod", "2015-01-07T20:50:10+00:00");
$myNewUri->addChild("changefreq", "daily");
$myNewUri->addChild("priority", "2.0");
```

Here, the first property is always required; that's the name of the XML node that you're adding. The second parameter is optional, but it specifies the text value to add to the new node. Do this for each of the links and you'll keep appending nodes

Finally, you want to print it out, no? To do that, use:

```
echo $sitemap->asXml();
```

If you want to save it to a file instead:

```
$sitemap->asXml("sitemap.xml");
```

Comment: Would this still be efficient even if I'm adding 100's of nodes a day?

Comment: That depends; if you're adding new ones each day (ie, ones that you didn't add the previous day), then that would probably be the easiest solution for you (unless you want to take on the complexity of managing everything as strings). So if you're saying your sitemap.xml grows by 100 every day, then this would probably be the solution. If it's staying the same each day and you're regenerating it, you should reevaluate how you're doing it. Also, it depends on how often and where this action takes place; for every user retrieval, or is it one time? Saving it as XML would be more optimal than echo

Comment: Alright, thanks! One last question, how would I check if an url is already in the sitemap using simplexml?

Comment: For this, I would recommend first checking out the PHP SimpleXMLIterator class documentation, specifically for the function SimpleXMLIterator::getChildren [here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmliterator.getchildren.php). You basically want to iterate over each child node <url>; of <urlset> and determine if any of the <loc> nodes of your current <url> equal the link in question.